# Hi, I am trying to install ROS hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.05 LTS. But it seems that hydro repository is not available?

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I added this Repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

As I tried it for the other repository that listed in ROS hydro installation.

But when I want to install ros hydro :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

It returns

```
Unable to locate package ros-hydro-desktop-full
```

Everything was working fine before last may!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328905/hi,-i-am-trying-to-install-ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-12.04.05-lts.-but-it-seems-that-hydro-repository-is-not-available?/) by [Rony_s](https://answers.ros.org/users/38957/rony_s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because of what is explained in #q325039, all older releases of ROS were moved to the *snapshot* repositories.

You'll want to read [SnapshotRepository](http://wiki.ros.org/SnapshotRepository) and setup your system to use the `final` snapshot of `hydro` for `precise`.

Edit: there is actually a Hydro snapshot available, even though `SnapshotRepository` does not list it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-07-18**:
The list is only for periodic snapshots. There are final snapshots for all EOL distros.